# Graph with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, eulerian-path

**G is a graph whose vertex set is $\{1,2, ... , 82\}$, vertices $i$ and $j$ are adjacent iff $|i-j| \mod 4 = 0 \text{ and } i \neq j$.**

(a) Calculate the chromatic number of $G$.

(b) Is $G$ Eulerian?

(c) Is $G$ planar?

I'm not sure how to go on about part (a) or part (c), for part (b), I tested cases manually like adjacent vertices of $1$ are $\{5, 9, ... , 81\}$ which are $20$ vertices, since degree of each vertex is even, it is Eulerian.

For part (c) I believe it should be enough to prove that there is a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subgraph but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I suggest drawing this graph for some smaller values in place of $82$. Once you know what the graph looks like, it will be much easier to answer all of these questions.

Comment: Your graph is composed of four subgraphs (two $K_{20}$, two $K_{21}$), not connected to each other. The answers to all three questions should follow immediately.

Comment: May I know the process you used to find that out?

Comment: $|i-j| \pmod 4 = 0$ is equivalent to $i \equiv j \pmod 4$. This means you can divide your vertices into 4 subsets based on the rest of their division by 4 where all vertices in the same set are adjacent to each other, and two vertices in different sets are not adjacent to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint (a):** Note that chromatic number of a complete graph $K_n$ is $n$ (Why?) and also think why this information is useful here (as an another hint, you can see the definition of complete graph).

**Hint (b):** When there are $20$ vertices and each vertex is adjacent to every other vertex, what is the degree of each vertex (This question is asked because for vertices $3$ and $4$, there is a difference)? Besides, we have some equivalence classes of nodes like nodes that are adjacent to $1$ can be represented by $[1]$ and similar to that, we have $[2]$, $[3]$ and $[4]$. If these are like equivalence classes, what can we say about them?

**Hint (c):** It is true that $K_5$ is not planar. What can we say about planarity of $K_n$ for $n \ge 5$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for (c).**
You are right to try to check if there is a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subgraph. Let's have a look for a $K_5$ -- what does this mean? It means that we have (distinct) vertices (ie natural numbers) $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, $n_4$ and $n_5$ so that they are all mutually adjacent. That is, we must have
$$ n_i \equiv n_j \mod 4 \quad \text{for all} \quad i,j \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$$
One can then try to come up with five numbers $\{n_1, ..., n_5\}$ satisfying these conditions.

Note that 'equivalence mod 4' is an equivalence relation: if $a \equiv b$ and $b \equiv c$ then $a \equiv c$ (mod 4). This makes it easier to find a complete subgraph, since we just need to find five *connected* points.

---

Now I've written this, it seems likely to me that you have stated the question incorrectly (although I could be mistaken!). Do you mean "$i$ and $j$ are adjacent if and only if $i \not\equiv j$ mod 4" (ie "are not equivalent mod 4" rather than "are equivalent mod 4")?
The latter is quite easy: we just need five numbers, all of whose differences are a multiple of four.
The former is harder: we need five numbers, *none* of whose differences are a multiple of four. (Question: is this possible?)

As noted in a comment below, a graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph that is a [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) of a $K_5$ or a $K_{3,3}$; this is [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem).

Comment: Certainly if there is a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subgraph, then $G$ is not planar. But if there is no such subgraph, then that doesn't guarantee that $G$ is planar! The criterion requires us to look for subgraphs that are *subdivisions* of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right! However, in this case, there is in fact a $K_{20}$ -- which leads me to think that the question is stated incorrectly

Comment: i and j are adjacent iff their difference is divisible by 4, and $i \neq j$. You are right, they are not equivalent mod 4.

Comment: When one says "equivalent mod 4", it means precisely that their difference is divisible by 4. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic] and/or [http://www.mathwords.com/m/modular_equivalence.htm]. Is that clear? :)